# How do i redirect using flask with an if function depending on the input of the user?

Tags: python, html, flask, redirect, python-requests

I'm new to trying creating websites using flask so I'm a bit confused.
essentially in the first HTML (website3.html) I have a page that opens and that gives the user the option to choose between option 1 and option 2.
In that html i used this portion of code:

```
  <form action="/redirect">
    <label for="option">Choose an option:</label>
    <select id="options" name="options">
      <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
      <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit">
  </form>
```

the /redirect page opens fine but then I just don't know how to redirect either to option1 / option2.
As you can see from my code below both options have their own template.
Once I run the code, the first page opens well. I select option 1 and then i get a 500 Internal Server Error.
Do you know what I'm missing to fix this redirection problem?
Thank you for all the help

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for
from flask_ngrok import run_with_ngrok
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from flask import request


app = Flask(__name__)
run_with_ngrok(app)

@app.route('/')
def home():
  return render_template('website3.html')

@app.route('/option1')
def option1():
  return render_template('option1.html')

@app.route('/option2')
def option2():
  return render_template('option2.html')

@app.route('/redirect')
def options():
  option = requests.args.get("options")
  if option == "Option 1": 
    return redirect("/option1")
  elif option == "Option 2":
    return redirect("/option2")
    

app.run()
```

Answer (score 2):

`requests` does not exist, I believe you mean `request`, so make sure you import it.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, request

@app.route('/redirect')
def options():
  option = request.args.get("options")
  if option == "option1": 
    return "<script>window.location.replace('/option1')</script>", 200
  elif option == "option2":
    return "<script>window.location.replace('/option2')</script>", 200
```

Another issue was your `option` ifs had a space between them. So I've corrected that. This should work.

It is a client-side redirect though. `window.location.replace` is used to hide /redirect when going through a browser history or pressing the back button on a browser, you can use `window.location = ""` if you prefer to.

Comment: Thank you so much this works, I was told there was a way to use redirect tho, do you know how i could do that?

Comment: Change `return "<script>window.location.replace('/option1')</script>", 200` to `return redirect(url_for('option1'))` and do the same for option 2 replacing the url wrapped in the url_for()

Answer (score 1):

I actually made it work by fixing several things, here is the updated code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, redirect
from flask_ngrok import run_with_ngrok
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from flask import request
import requests


app = Flask(__name__)
run_with_ngrok(app)

@app.route('/')
def home():
  return render_template('website3.html')


@app.route('/redirect')
def options():
  option = request.args.get("options")
  if option == "option1": 
    return redirect("/option1")
  elif option == "option2":
    return redirect("/option2")
   


@app.route('/option1')
def option1():
  return render_template('option1.html')

@app.route('/option2')
def option2():
  return render_template('option2.html')
app.run()
```

Thank you for the help